# Converting list of values from MySQL into array with square brackets

Tags: php, mysql, json, vue.js, axios

I want to display a chart with ApexCharts from MySQL data.

I am connecting to my database via axios and a php-file with functions that communicate with the database. A typical vue method looks like:

```
myfunction: function(){
  axios.post('ajaxfile.php', {
    request: 1,
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    alert(response.data);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
  },
```

In ajaxfile.php this request is being continued like this and echoed back as json encoded:

```
if($request == 1){
$data = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from mytable");

  $result = array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){
    $result[]=$row;
  }
  echo json_encode($result);
  exit;
}
```

ApexCharts pulls data in the data section of vue.js like this, which (in this case) is the base for a pie chart with 30% and 70% data:

```
data: {
    chartdata: [30, 70],
}
```

What I’d like to achieve is selecting two numeric values from my database in my ajaxfile.php and create a pie chart from it. So something like:

```
if($request == 1){
$data1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from mytable WHERE id=1");
  $result1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data1);

$data2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from mytable WHERE id=2");
  $result2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data2);

 $chartdata = $result1.','.$result2;

  echo json_encode($chartdata);
  exit;
}
```

And in Vue.js:

```
  myfunction: function(){
      axios.post('ajaxfile.php', {
        request: 1,
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        app.chartdata = response.data;
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
      },
```

The chartdata from my ajaxfile should then be saved in app.chartdata in vue, so that ApexCharts can build the chart from it.

But how can I achieve the needed format?

```
[30,70]
```

I pretty much tried everything. Even rebuilding the format with additional brackets didn't help. Like:

```
app.chartdata ="[ "+app.chartdata +" ]";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are way to do it in javascript, below is an approach to do it in MySQL.

When `select * from mytable` produces:

| id |
| --- |
| 30 |
| 70 |

You can do `select group_concat(id) as id from mytable`, and get:

| id |
| --- |
| 30,70 |

or even:

```
select concat('[',group_concat(id),']') as id from mytable
```

and get:

| id |
| --- |
| [30,70] |

Comment: This works! I think there might have been a problem trying to convert things in javascript. The approach to do it directly in mysql works perfectly! Thanks!